# jquery, add text into specific label's <small> tag

Tags: php, jquery

having some issue in getting text append into specific label

here is my html code

```
<label for="password">
    Password <small>required</small>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"/>
    <small class="error">Password is required</small>
    <small class="server-error"></small>
</label>
```

now when my server validation return as false with the msg, i would like to append that message into the `<small class="server-error"></small>`

here is my ajax part

```
$.post('./login.php', $(this).serialize(), function(msg){
    //  working = false;
    //  $('#submit').val('Login');
    if(msg.status){
        window.location.href = "testt.php";
    }
    else {
        $.each(msg.errors,function(k,v){
            /// NOT SURE WHAT TO HAVE HERE TO GET THE SPECIFIC LABEL 
        });
        //$('#testForm').html("fail");
    }
}, 'json');
```

Comment: How is `msg.errors` structured?

Comment: it will return k = as the label name eg "password" and v = as the error message

Comment: previous way i am doing like this $('label[for='+k+']').append('<span class="error">'+
      v+'</span>'); but rite now wanted to have it inside the small server-error class

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.each(msg.errors,function(k,v){
           $("label[for=" + k +"]").find(".server-error").append("<br>" + v);
        });
```

This code will show error of columns in their respective error div.

Comment: why the `find()`? You can just use `$("label[for=" + k +"] small.server-error").append("<br>" + v);`

Comment: @FabiandePabian even better :)

Comment: hmm is not working on my end with that, is it actually because i am using the foundation zurb responsive abide form format?

Comment: no i can see you are using zurb..but that should not affect that..are you sure about the msg.errors ?

Comment: from my firebug, response i saw this return back 
{"status":0,"errors":{"password":"Wrong Password"}} but i dont see that message on the frontend

Comment: i am not sure if the function(k,v) is actually fetching as u said..can you please log the k,v's and show us

Comment: Object { password="Wrong Password"} this is what i get from the firebug console in log